# Why was a regular train used to transport students to Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-transportation, transportation

To get to Hogwarts, the students had to:

- Travel many hours by regular (seemingly non-magical, and fairly slow) train
- Then get into magical conveyances in Hogsmeade.

The latter makes sense - you can't apparate in Hogwarts.

But WHY oh WHY did they need a regular train?

Why not:

- A magic school bus (like Knight one) to Hogsmeade
- A magic flying dis-illusioned train
- A bunch of portkeys (heck, they used them to transport the wizards to Quidditch cup in 1994, and IIRC there were a LOT more attendees than students at Hogwarts)!
- And, at worst, for a couple of Muggle-born students who for some reason can't get to any of the above, arrange something much smaller than a train.

Comment: It's surely far more interesting and exciting to get the train? Much better than a rickety old bus? (Just think how big that bus would have been?)

Comment: Based on the fact that it can make a trip in a single "BANG", and therefore transport students in batches - not very big.

Comment: Magicking a train to fly invisibly would be a violation of the laws about Misuse of Muggle Artifacts.  They couldn't even claim the loophole Mr. Weasley used, in that they obviously intended the invisible flying train to be used.  Also, they'd have to watch out for low-flying planes.

Comment: Why do you think it was a regular train? Hogwarts' location is hidden. It should be hard to get to it by ordinary means.

Comment: @Jeff - um... they are the Ministry. They could change their own rules to accommodate the train. personally, I'd expect making a flying train hidden from Muggles is a wee bit easier than a regular surface one.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I meant ordinary as in, it uses steam engine to drive around regular surface tracks with a speed of (or less than) ordinary Muggle trains. It may have some magic in it as far as stealth, but not as far as transportation

Comment: @DVK: Hogwarts =/= Ministry.  There could be an exception made, true, but...well, see my answer.

Comment: @Jeff - it's kind of all the same system. Hogwarts is not FULLY separate and autonomous from the Ministry, as the events of OotP and DH show - and obviously Headmasters/Hogwarts in general have influence at the Ministry, leaving aside personal squabbles between Fudge and Dumbledore. I agree that your answer provides a good rationale for why you wouldn't WANT a fast flying train.

Comment: @Jeff The misuse of muggle artifacts law is relatively recent and the train pre-dates the law.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian it was a regular train, but magically "hidden" by a concealment charm.

Comment: Plot device.  I can't think of any other reason.

Comment: @acolyte - unless otherwise noted, most questions on SFF.SE are asked in the context of "in-universe", meaning the asker is not usually seeking an obvious and/or trivial answer like "plot hole", "plot device", or "without this, the work would not be interesting" (with the caveat exception of the work's author explicitly admitting such).

Comment: @DVK hence why i didn't write up an answer.  Canon-wise, no reason is given.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that, even if you don't accept my speculative reasoning (which is not canon, but based upon it), the next highest-voted answer does cite canon sources and provide a good explanation.  You should accept that answer.

Comment: @Jeff - done. I'd upvote you for a sens of fair play, but I already upvoted back when you posted the answer :(

Comment: I stand by my answer 100%, and would have loved to see it accepted.  That said, you said you wanted to see a canon/WoG answer if possible, so I figured I'd point it out to you :-)  In the end, the site is slightly better for everyone, so we all win.  Plus, I bet I get a badge for 'Answer score > 2x accepted answer'.

Comment: @Jeff Gold Badge >> Accept 15 rep :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the article, "Hogwarts Express" on Pottermore (Or, "Potterless" :-), for a long time parents were responsible for transportation to and from the school.  Of course apparating and flue powder were out of the question in order to get directly into the school (because of protective security measures), but other than that there were an assortment of forms of transportation used.

> Some rode broomsticks (a difficult feat when carrying trunks and
>   pets); others commandeered enchanted carts and, later, carriages; some
>   attempted to Apparate (often with disastrous effects, as the castle
>   and grounds have always been protected with Anti-Apparition Charms),
>   others rode a variety of magical creatures.

This posed a problem in drawing the attention of Muggles when witches were seen on brooms and, or in flying carriages and the like (pre- "International Secrecy Act" and also pre-"Misuse of Muggle Artifacts" law).  The article does not address how transportation was planned out for Muggle-borns at this time (or at any other time really).

> Despite Muggle sightings of vast numbers of airborne wizards travelling
>   northwards, it remained the responsibility of parents to convey their
>   children to school, right up until the imposition of the International
>   Statute of Secrecy in 1692. At this point, it became a matter of
>   urgency to find some more discreet method of transporting hundreds of
>   wizarding children from all over Britain to their secret school in the
>   Highlands of Scotland.

Rowling goes on to say that portkeys were arranged and tried but many children got "portkey sick" and the first few days of school were spent in the infirmary for many students.  Additionally, Portkeys posed problems because the keys were hard to find and many kids would miss them.

> While admitting that Portkeys were not an ideal solution to the
>   problem of school transportation, the Ministry of Magic failed to find
>   an acceptable alternative. A return to the unregulated travel of the
>   past was impossible, and yet a more secure route into the school (for
>   instance, permitting a fireplace that might be officially entered by
>   Floo powder) was strongly resisted by successive Headmasters, who did
>   not wish the security of the castle to be breached.

Eventually the train was established - Muggles were even used in its building and then their memories of the years spent building it, erased.

> Where exactly the Hogwarts Express came from has never been
>   conclusively proven, although it is a fact that there are secret
>   records at the Ministry of Magic detailing a mass operation involving
>   one hundred and sixty-seven Memory Charms and the largest ever mass
>   Concealment Charm performed in Britain.

This solution was highly controversial, but proved to solve the problem and has been maintained ever since.

> Many pure-blood families were outraged at the idea of their children
>   using Muggle transport, which they claimed was unsafe, insanitary and
>   demeaning; however, as the Ministry decreed that students either rode
>   the train or did not attend school, the objections were swiftly
>   silenced.

She does not discuss why some form of a "knight bus" like apparatus or magic flying train was not used, however, I'd bet that despite the long hours, its a great deal more comfortable than long hours on a broom and perhaps no one minds that part. :-)

A rare event like the World Quiddich cup that will bring in revenue from tourists is likely to be seen as a one-time and worthwhile imposition on the ministry, whereas repeated yearly requirements would seem more like drudgery.  I do remember getting the feeling that it was quite a challenge getting all the keys arranged - lots of "magical red tape" so to speak.  If the Ministry was going to all that trouble back in the day for Hogwarts only to have a large percentage of the kids miss their times, I'd bet they didn't care if the solution was quick and easy for the students, so long as it was quicker and easier for ministry officials.

The quotes here come from snippets of the article by Rowling herself on Pottermore titled, "Hogwart's Express."

Comment: @DVK Bibidibobidiboo!

Comment: According to Wikipedia, trains were not used to transport people until the 1800s. With the International Statute of Secrecy being established in 1692, this means the magical world was "experimenting" with transportation methods for at least 150 years. I know the wizarding world moves slowly, but come on.

Comment: This isn't counting the Roman Empire having a proto-train 2600 years ago, of course.

Comment: Why should students who live much closer to Hogwarts than to London be forced to travel all the way to London just to get on a train that takes hours? Even if they can travel to Diagon Alley instantaneously by Floo powder, it seems an enormous waste of time.

Comment: "Of course apparating and flue powder were out of the question in order to get directly into the school (because of protective security measures)"  How was Sirius able to use Floo Powder, then?

Answer (score 51):

I think the only possible answer is the Muggle-borns.

Obviously, the wizarding world has to stay secret from Muggles.  But they also must recruit untrained wizards from the Muggle families that birthed them.

Say you're a parent.  Your child has always seemed...odd.  Different somehow.  Special.  Interesting things happen around them - often unexplainable, but you rationalize it.

Then they turn 11, and an OWL arrives carrying a parchment letter, sealed with wax, that shatters your world (it could also come by post, of course, which wouldn't change things much).  The letter to your child says that magic is real, and your child is a wizard.  Your plans for their education go out the window - they have this potential that they must develop.

Most Muggles have never considered magic even potentially real, not since they were children.  The thought that there may actually be witches and wizards will frighten you, at some level.

You journey, possibly aided by a mysterious witch or wizard - one of your child's new teachers, to a place you had never imagined could be in London - Diagon Alley.  There you see obvious magic, you see potion ingredients that may sicken you, you see, smell, and hear bizarre things.

Perhaps you are calmed and reassured by the teacher.  Perhaps Diagon Alley helps you come to terms with things.  Perhaps, after all of this, you are actually looking forward to seeing your child grow into a wizard or witch.

Then the Knight Bus shows up, BANG!ing around, careening to and fro with no apparent regard for anyone's safety.

Or maybe a teacher shows up out of nowhere, and makes your child vanish before your eyes.

Or perhaps there's a portkey that they use, and you see your child dragged away by an old boot.

Or they could use a train.  A bit old fashioned, it's steam-driven, but you take your child to a perfectly normal train station, enter Platform 9 <sup>3/4</sup>, and see them board a train that chugs away.

Which way will scare a Muggle parent least?

Also consider the psychological effect on the new Muggle-born student: They leave their parent in a fairly normal way, and their true introduction to the wizarding world is slow - they meet their fellow students, see some minor magics performed.  They see interesting and magical treats on the cart.  They interact with older students, and the people they'll be spending the next several months living with.

Then, a few hours later, as the sun drops towards the horizon, they get their first view of Hogwarts - a mighty castle, thrusting tall into the darkening sky.  Every window blazes with light, and you are awed.

By this point, you are not just ready to learn magic, you are EAGER.  Ask any teacher, they'll tell you: the best students are those who are motivated to learn.

**TL;DR:** It makes the separation easier for Muggle parents and eases the transition of Muggle-borns into the Wizarding world.  It also helps drive the students to want to learn, making the teacher's jobs that much easier.

Comment: The logic seems pretty sound - +1. I'll wait around a bit for some fairy godmother to drop a canon quote or Word of God on my lap before accepting...

Comment: The only thing what can possibly added is that the train can not be considered "non-magical" at all. It travels through inhabited area at least in and around London, most likely on existing tracks, without been detected by muggles. It can very likely pass through solid matter and remain invisible.

Comment: @vsz: Thing is, it isn't invisible - Harry and Ron could follow it from above easily in book 2.

Comment: @Jeff: then how can it avoid being detected by muggles? The railroad system is not something where you can just run a train out of schedule with no questions asked, especially a steam locomotive in the last decade of the 20th century without being seen. It's either a plot hole, or only wizards can see it.

Comment: @Jeff It could just be invisible to muggles, like Hogwarts and the Quidditch Cup arena. At least once it's left the station, otherwise the whole "easing muggle parents into it" thing goes out the window when their kids board an invisible train.

Comment: @jono: But neither of those are invisible to Muggles.  The Quidditch Cup stadium is surrounded by "avoid this area" charms - explicitly stated to not be invisible - and the castle itself is completely visible, just has an illusion to make it look like a decrepit old empty castle with a 'Condemned' sign.

Comment: @Jeff well whatever you wish to call it, "invisible" or "undetectable" or "unacknowledgable", they still accomplish the same thing: keeping muggles from interacting or reacting to its presence

Answer (score 2):

Based on some of the events in the first book, I assumed when reading the books and watching the movies that the reason was firstly because of tradition.  Especially when you consider the first years had to travel over to the castle by boats.  Surely there was a better means than a boat.  Then secondly - I was stationed in Europe for several years and found that the most common means of travel in Europe and England is by train.  Since the magical world wanted to remain hidden from the muggle world it would make sense then to just go by a secret train that the muggles couldn't see.  When I consider these two points, the train seems to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The train is a symbolic journey of leaving the muggle world behind and entering the wizarding world. Forms of instantaneous magical transport do not accomplish this. There is nothing like a long train ride where you can watch the muggle world receding in the distance, and then a few hours later see the wizarding world emerging on the horizon.

In short it is an age-old psychological phenomenon that is used to demonstrate that they are leaving one world behind and immersing themselves totally in their wizarding schooling, uninterrupted by outside happenings until the end of the semester. It is, in essence, a transitional location in which the young students straddle two worlds and move from one to the other.The state of mind this creates is simply non-existent in most magical forms of travel.

See for example the following quote:

**Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter Six**

> Harry watched the girl and her mother disappear as  the train rounded
>   the corner. Houses flashed past the  window. Harry felt a great leap
>   of excitement. He  didn’t know what he was going to — but it had to be
>   better than what he was leaving behind.

Answer (score 1):

Also JK Rowling wanted to have a nod to older boarding school books where there is normal a train ride (I can't name any off the top of my head)

Comment: Do you have any source or reference to back up this statement? Something from a commentary or interview, perhaps?

Comment: I just remember it was from a book I read but I can't remember what the book was-only the book was red

Comment: Notably, this is the opening sequence to Prince Caspian, the second of C.S. Lewis' _Narnia_ series: _… and now all four of them were sitting on a seat at a railway station with trunks and playboxes piled up round them. They were, in fact, on their way back to school. They had travelled together as far as this station, which was a junction; and here, in a few minutes, one train would arrive and take the girls away to one school, and in about half an hour another train would arrive and the boys would go off to another school._

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it was to form friendships. eg The Marauders, Harry Potter, Ron Weasley, Hermione Granger, Snape. So basically it's a friendship train that allows people to get to know each other.

Comment: There’s no basis to think that the people who decided to use the Hogwarts Express as student transport had that in mind. There’d be time enough at Hogwarts itself to make friends.

Comment: @Bellatrix From an in-universe view, sure. But from a storytelling point of view... well, this is what happens, so....

Comment: @mattdm Yes, the question is asked about the in-universe reason, so answers should be based on a possible reason in-universe.