# Where is Platform 9 3/4 located?

Tags: harry-potter, plot-device

King Cross's Platform 9 <sup>3</sup>/<sub>4</sub>: we can go *"there"* by throwing ourselves on the wall between Platforms 9 and 10.

But *where* is that *"there"*?

Is it on King's Cross? Then *where* at King's Cross?

What is this *"there"*???

Comment: First 3 "questions" are the same question and not really addressed in canon as far as I know. The last question is a duplicate of [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10275/why-was-a-regular-train-used-to-transport-students-to-hogwarts)

Comment: @DVK ok, but then how come this is _too broad_?

Comment: you're asking 4 (or at least 2) separate questions

Comment: @DVK you said first three are same, and I removed the last one.... And btw, the second one is a confirmatory test.

Comment: If you go to King's Cross Station you'll see it. It's just next to the Harry Potter shop, by the queue of tourists. Harry Potter stands there most days, and if you ask him nicely he'll lend you his scarf to wear while your friends and family take photos of you. If you're planning on using it to go to Hogwarts, you're out of luck–there's a trolley wedged halfway in the magical portal that seems to be blocking it up.

Comment: I thought it was actually at Paddington and JK Rowling got it muddled up?

Comment: Don't bother trying to find it in King's Cross.  The Hogwarts Express departs from a different station to avoid unwanted attention by people trying to witness the scene described in the Epilogue.

Comment: @Nick:  See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68001/4918 Had JK Rowling seen King's Cross Station before writing the first book?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Harry and Ron were able to follow it in the flying car during *Chamber of Secrets* pretty much straight after it left the station, I think we should conclude that it's just a platform located somewhere in (or very near to) King's Cross station that is hidden - just like its entrance - from Muggles. I really don't think we're going to get more precise than that, though.

As for why the gateway to the hidden platform doesn't just lead straight to Hogwarts, that's a great question. It has kind of been addressed already in this question: [Why was a regular train used to transport students to Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10275/why-was-a-regular-train-used-to-transport-students-to-hogwarts)

Comment: Obviously, it's between platform 9 and platform 10, but it's closer to the latter than the former. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is as many people know located between platforms 9/10. Harry and Ron can get to it by using the car which means it is accessible through more than one approach. If you have watched the last film where hagrid takes harry to the burrows where everyone underage takes pollyjuice potion to look like harry. At the end where hagrid regains consciousness the flying motorbike is seen to pass through a puff of cloud before it is clearly visible that the burrows is there. I'm only assuming that you have to be of magical blood to be able to see the track and the hogwarts express so to the naked eye it is just fields?? Correct me if I'm chatting utter pixie poo this means that it is in a lost location that only wizards and witches know about?